# How to decode p7s sign properly

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, asn.1, pkcs#7

I have 2 pkcs7 signs. One of the can be easily decoded with http://lapo.it/asn1js/, while another cannot. I've opened those 2 files with Windows Notepad and one of them(which can be easily decoded) is shown like this(only the beginning)

**0‚я   *†H†ч
 ‚р0‚м10**

Weird, but this can be decoded. Moreover, notepad says that it's ANSI encoding.

On the other hand, my second file looks like 'normal'

**MIIMMwYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIMJDCCDCACAQExDDAKBgYqhQMCAgkFADALBgkqhkiG**

and so on and so forth. 
Notepad says it's UTF-8 encoding. But I cannot verify who's the owner with ASN.1 decoder. The file just cannot be processed at all. I can figure this out only with Windows build-in utility. How can I make it to be decoded normally with ASN.1?

Comment: Actually, it can be processed, but only if I provide "normal" code to the field below "ASN.1 JavaScript decoder". If I provide a file, it can not.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. In the first case p7s sign is **hex-encoded**, while in the second it's **Base64** encoded. Based on this I should choose decoding algorithm.